# readOnly flag on Spring Transactional annotation and persistent context

Tags: spring, transactions, entitymanager, readonly

Reading about the readOnly flag on Spring transactional annotation, it says from the javadoc *"This just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem; it will not necessarily cause failure of write access attempts. A transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction"*.

1. But its said that marking with readOnly, the entities retrieved from database wont be stored in the persistent context or other way to say it is that the firt level cache is disabled because entities wont be stored in  the persistent context. Is this right?
2. If this is right, why if I call entityManager.contains() it always returns true although I marked the transactional with readOnly true?
3. How can I test really with JPA if the entities are really stored in the persistent context?

Thanks

Comment: 1. No, 2. Because 1 isn't right 3. you already do that.

Comment: So you are saying that Persistent context store entities despite the fact that readOnly is marked with true?. Why does Persistent Context stores them then?. Why is needed if there is no need to store them because updates, deletes, etc are avoided in this kind of transaction?

Comment: No. They are still in the first level cache but with a flag that they are readonly and so aren't dirty checked. The fact that they are in the persistence context doesn't mean they aren't in the first level cache! The `EntityManager` **is** the first level cache.

Comment: According to this https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-persistence-context#:~:text=The%20persistence%20context%20is%20the,or%20saved%20to%20the%20database.&text=Persistence%20context%20keeps%20track%20of,entity%20is%20marked%20as%20dirty., persistent context is the first level cache

Comment: The `EntityManager` is the persistence context and thus the first level cache.

Comment: But you say Persistent context is different from first level cache, right?

Comment: No I'm for the third time iterating that `EntityManager` == persisentce context == first level cache.